# Scrolling a webpage inside UIWebView

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` and `UIButton` added as subview to my View.  I also have a large webpage displayed inside my `UIWebView`, is it possible to scroll the webpage by clicking a button on the `UIView`?

I want to make the webpage scroll untill it reaches the bottom of the document.

The javascript to be used is : `window.scrollTo(xPos, yPos);`

Is it possible to make a javascript call on the button action which will scroll the web document inside the `UIWebView`?

Answer (score 5):

You can use that on your UIWebview component:

```
NSString *yourScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"javascript_method();"]; 
NSString* responseJS = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:yourScript];
```

Answer (score 1):

Scroll the UIWebView by calling JavaScript through Objective-C:

```
NSString *script = @"scrollTo(0, 0)";
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
```

For smooth scrolling, use a library like jQuery:

```
NSString *script = @"$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow')";
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:script];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement when I wanted to scroll the `UIWebview` Programmatically as I had no control over the web-pages I was loading. I wanted a way to do it in my ObjC code.

Solution:
 `UIWebview` has is own `UIScrollView` we can play with it
1. Set the Edge inset for the `_webview` to whatever you want.
2. Then tell the `_webview` to scroll to the specified position.

```
[[_webView scrollView]setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-300, 0, 0, 0)];
[[_webView scrollView]scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, -300, 768, 1024) animated:YES];
```